# How can I test with Jest for setState

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

How can I test a setState with Jest? I want to test when I called a function that update the state.

```
const TmpComponent = () => {
  const [resut, setResult] = useState(0);

  const increaseResult = (amountToIncrease) => {
    setResult(prev => prev + amountToIncrease);
  };
};
```

How can I test the `increaseResult` function? I want to test whether the result is updated by calling the function.

Have to try the other way? Only I need to add parameter the result for testing this function?

Comment: The best practice when testing React components would be to test the output, not the internals of the function. Doing this requires thinking about testing in a different way. Instead of testing that state is updated (which the user cares nothing about), test that you component displays the correct thing after whatever interaction causes the state update.

Comment: @BrianThompson oh! thank you! so I'm trying the other way you mentioned..!  like testing the result of the reflected view by react-state!! thanks, now I know the concept of the react-testing thanks for you!!